# How to set a SearchView text value in search widget ActionBar?

Tags: android

my actionBar menu contains two actons: standard action_search and action_scan barcode. After scanning a barcode with zxing i would like to call a searchView with a barcode scan content value from onActivityResult, ist it possible? or maybe there is another way to do this?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.artikel_liste, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            Log.d("Filter","on query submit: "+query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);            
            Log.d("Filter","on change text: "+newText);

            return true;
        }
    };

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    //retrieve scan result
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null) {
        //we have a result
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();


        // how to call a searchView ??

        //SearchView(searchView).setQuery(scanContent, true);  
        //search.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        //searchView.setQuery("test", false);

        //test
        //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FORMAT: "+scanFormat+" ,CONTENT: "+scanContent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        //toast.show();

    }else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get you, do you wanna add search in widget?

Comment: i would like to call a search widget with barcode content in onActivityResult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you should consider:

1) onCreateOptionsMenu will only get called when it is first created. You will want to use onPrepareOptionsMenu once it is reloaded.

2) You can tell the ActionBar to refresh using the following method:

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

So inside your onActivityResult you can set a boolean, then call invalidateOptionsMenu(), the onPrepareOptionsMenu will get hit and you can play with the searchView as necessary.

Hope it helps.

Good Luck